# Having proble with strategy.exit

Tags: pine-script

I’m making an indicator.
The problem is when i add it to the chart the exit does not work properly.
when my indicator buys it immediately sells one candle after i bought in.

I’m making an indicator where i want to sell at a loss or a profit. I’m using 2 ternary oparators. One that i call longStop and the other one is called longProfit.I already tried the stop/limit/profit/loss function but not a single one seems to work so far.

```
//@version=4
strategy("Daily ATR Stop", overlay=true)
//========================================================long entery.
high1 = high[100]
high2 = highest(high, 99)
long = float(na)
long := high2 < high1 ? high1 : long[1]
long_cond = crossover(close, long)

if long_cond
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

//long profit//
low1 = low[30]
low2 = lowest(low,29)
longProfit = float(na)
longProfit := low1 < low2 ? low1 : longProfit[1]
atrLkb = input(7, minval=1, title='ATR Stop Period')
atrRes = input("D", type=input.resolution, title='ATR Resolution')
atrMult = input(1, step=0.25, title='ATR Stop Multiplier')
atr = security(syminfo.tickerid, atrRes, atr(atrLkb))
longStop = float(na)
longStop := long_cond and strategy.position_size <= 0 ? close - atr * 
atrMult : longStop[1]
// i have a problem whith the exit part  
strategy.exit("exit","My Long Entry Id", stop=longStop, 
profit=longProfit)

plot(longProfit)
plot(longStop)
plot(long)
```

[image]

Comment: What is `low2`?

Comment: Also, could you please attach a screenshot of the Strategy Tester?

Comment: low2 = lowset(low,29)

Answer (score 0):

Your `profit` target seems to be very low.

It's a good thing that you plot `longProfit` and `longStop`, but have you ever looked at what values they have? I recommend you giving different colors to diffferent plot, so you can see which is which.

Here is a screenshot of your strategy where you have "problem". Green line is your profit target, and red line is your stop target.

[image]

As you can see, price is above your profit target and you are actually taking profit.

Comment: Thx for the help i realy 
appreciate it! if you have 
any 
idea how i can fix this just let me know.

Comment: It's up to you. You just need to raise your profit limit. You can try something like this: `longProfit := max(high1, high2)`

Comment: l = float(na)
    l := longStop > longProfit ? longStop : longProfit > longStop ? longProfit : l[1]

Comment: As I said, it is you who should decide when you should take profit.